# Get records in two lines with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have some data in multiple tables i want to join that tables and need to display the result as multiple records below is the table structure

```
          main_table                           
   id     name   height                
   1      test1  5.2                     
   2      test2  4.6                    

          child_table                         
   id  main_table_id  name   height     
   1       1          test3  5.3         
   2       1          test4  4.5
```

expecting result like

```
   id  name    height   

   1   test1   5.2      
   1   test3   5.3
   1   test4   4.5
```

How can i achive this using query in MySql expecting suggestions how can i achieve this?

Comment: why isn't the result corresponding to `id = 2` not showing ?

Comment: what you have tried for that?

Answer (score 1):

Use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT id, name, height 
FROM main_table 
WHERE id = 1

UNION 

SELECT main_table_id as id, name, height 
FROM child_table 
WHERE main_table_id = 1
```

Comment: I forgot about union, Thank you is solved my problem

Comment: @user3668438 if it works for you, you may kindly upvote and accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using left and colasce

```
select maintable.id,COALESCE(maintable.name,childtable.name) as name,
COALESCE(maintable.height,childtable.height) 
from maintable left join childtable
on maintable.id=childtable.main_table_id
where maintable.id=1
```